# How to add a new column into an existing DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a synthetic data column to the existing the movies dataset. This new column is the gross revenue of an actor's second most recent movie.

For example:

| Movie | Actor | Revenue | *New Column** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Nic Cage | $7 | $5 |
| B | Nic Cage | $6 | $4 |
| C | Nic Cage | $5 | - |
| D | Nic Cage | $4 | - |
| E | Al Pacino | $3 | $1 |
| F | Al Pacino | $2 | - |
| G | Al Pacino | $1 | - |

What is the most efficient way to code this in python?

Comment: This looks like homework. Can you give us your best attempt and we can make suggestions?

Comment: Second most recent?  I don't see any dates here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the movies are sorted, use [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html)

```
df['New Column'] = df.groupby('Actor')['Revenue'].shift(-2, fill_value='-')
```

Output:

```
  Movie      Actor Revenue New Column
0     A   Nic Cage      $7         $5
1     B   Nic Cage      $6         $4
2     C   Nic Cage      $5          -
3     D   Nic Cage      $4          -
4     E  Al Pacino      $3         $1
5     F  Al Pacino      $2          -
6     G  Al Pacino      $1          -
```